# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found. Anybody?

Tags: python, unicode

```
   while(i<=9):
        proto_actual=lista[i][0]
        puerto_actual=lista[i][1]
        if("UDP" in proto_actual):
            udp1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            udp1.sendto("toc,toc", (host,int(puerto_actual)))
            udp1.close()
            i=i+1
        else:
            tcp1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            print "Socket creado"
            tcp1.sendto("toc,toc", (host,int(puerto_actual)))
            tcp1.close()
            print "hola"
            i=i+1
```

Any body can help me? I got this :

```
File "cliente.py", line 43, in <module>
   udp1.sendto("toc,toc"+ (host,int(puerto_actual)))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
```

and I dont see any problem on the code.
I am doing a program like port knocking. 
Thanks!

Comment: How many arguments does `udp1.sendto` take?

Comment: it seems you put wrong code in question - there is no `"toc,toc"+ (host,int(puerto_actual)` as error shows. Or you run different code than you think.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to error in the line which you haven't either shared here or may be the typo in the code you are using (but eventually corrected it while sharing here). As the error message says, the issue is with the line:

```
udp1.sendto("toc,toc"+ (host,int(puerto_actual)))
#                    ^ replace with ,
```

Here `"toc,toc" +` means you want to concatenate the `str` with the tuple object `(host,int(puerto_actual)` which is not a valid operation. In order to fix this, replace `+` with comma `,`